# BackgroundImage is squeezed

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I write a visual part of my page in XAML. 
My issue is: I’ve got  BackgroundImage  below my  text and my BackgroundImage  is squeezed. I need my  BackgroundImage picture to be cut if it is not fitted.
[Right now my BackgroundImage is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkROB.png)

But I want BackgroundImage to be like that - [desired background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apEQd.png) and over it I want ScrollView text.

I’ve searched everything it is possible but I don’t get how to do it. 
The structure of my page is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HelloApp.View.Page2"
             BackgroundImage="WashingtonPicture.jpg">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Padding = "50">
          <Label TextColor="Black" FontSize ="Large">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text=""/>
                              ...
                              ...
```